# intl PHP extension is not working for xampp server

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to install `CakePHP 3-0-0` version and I have downloaded the source code from [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/3.0.0). But it is showing the error of enable `intl extension`. As I have already changed `;extension=php_intl.dll` to `extension=php_intl.dll` (remove the semicolon) in `php.ini` file and restart xampp `2-3` times, but still it is showing that same error.

Here is the error below:

```
Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in D:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-3-0-0\config\bootstrap.php on line 38
```

So, can anyone please tell me what is the issue here? And what should I do to resolved this issue?

Comment: make sure you have edited correct `ini` file, you can see which `ini` is currently in use by `<?php phpinfo() ?>` and search for ini.

Comment: Yeah, I have modified correct `ini` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have activated the `php_intl.dll` in the php.ini file you also need to copy the dll files that `php_intl.dll` uses from the PHP folder to the Apache/bin folder.

I am not a XAMPP user so I am not sure of the actual folder names

copy xampp/php/icu*.dll to xamp\apache\bin

Also remember that you have to edit the php.ini file that lives in the `\xampp\apache\bin` folder and not the one in the `\xampp\php` folder.

The one in the `\xampp\php` folder only gets used by PHP CLI (Command Line Interface)

Comment: I already have `php_intl.dll` file into its respective directory `xampp/php/ext`. But still its not working.

Comment: You are not reading all the answer. You need to copy the `icu*.dll` files **FROM** the php folder **TO** the `apache\bin` folder. There are about 8 of these files

Comment: Oops Sorry!! its my mistake that one file was missing to copy. Now its working fine. Thanks -:).

Comment: There is no `xampp/php` in my case, but I do see `xampp/xamppfiles/php` but again I cannot find `icu*.dll` nor php_intl.dll`. I am lost here.

Comment: I am a WAMPServer user so I not totally familiar with XAMPP structure. I just download a XAMPP and `icu*.dll` files are in the `xampp/php` folder and the intl.dll is in `xampp\php\ext`. If you installed in a non default place then you will have to extrapolate these onto your folder structure

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem was to restart Apache process. Restart in XAMPP control panel by clicking Stop and Start is not enough. I had to run Task Manager and kill httpd.exe process. Then run XAMPP again. That solve problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if you are using OSX

Steps from http://www.phpzce.com/blog/view/15/installing-intl-package-on-your-mac-with-xampp

1. Check which php path is set i.e.

   root$: which php
2. If you are using xampp on your mac it should be

   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php

but if its

```
/usr/bin/php
```

you need to change your OSx php

```
root$: PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:${PATH}"
```

3. Install icu4c

   root$: brew install icu4c
4. Install Intl via PECL

   root$: sudo pecl update-channels 
   root$: sudo pecl install intl
5. You can check if Intl was installed successfully

   root$: php -m | grep intl #should return 'intl'

Done

Answer (score 0):

For me (not using any xampp, just Apache 2.4 and php 5.5. installed on Windows 7):

After uncommenting the intl-extension in php.ini, it didn't come active cause I only RESTARTED Apache server!

This is best to observe from phpinfo() page (try to find intl).

So I think the problem was solved when I stop and start the Apache server. (Probably same problem as in [kaligari answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32739237/2628285))

While trying solutions I moved the php folder and changed the folder to Apache conf file BUT forgot to change the environmental variable path to php, so after while I found this and got it work.

> Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environmental variables->Path->Check
>   php folder is there [Thanks to Gregory Karpinsky](http://www.tiv.net/2010/12/php-intl-extension-windows-apache.html)

SO CHECK THAT IF EXTENSION IS STILL NOT LOADING!

No need to copy any files from php->apache\bin. This is probably because I'm not using xampp BUT it is necessery to actually STOP and START over the Apache service to get it to reload the php extensions and have the path environmental variable correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured basic settings, try to restart xampp...It worked for me.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: why do have pita if I answer directly but not in comments !