# PHP Extension intl. error in Mac while installing Magento using XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, magento, xampp

I'm facing PHP Extension intl. error while installing magento(2.3.3) using XAMPP(7.2.26)
[image]

As mentioned in the other references, I installed intl and added **extension=intl.so** in **php.ini** file, still facing the same issue.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You are checking you php-cli. Does the server has the same config?
What does `phpinfo` say when u run it in the browser?

Comment: As you are using XAMPP, you need to enable the extension in your PHP folder that is under Apache, not the PHP one only. PHP one is for `php-cli`, apache uses the PHP that is under its folder.

Comment: Check this out for the right solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30481168/1334933