# You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP on line 31

Tags: php, cakephp, cmd, cakephp-3.x, intl

As Cakephp is successfully installed and its showing the main page.

It's giving this error while running the cake command in the cmd,

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephpwork\bin>cake
PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephpwork\config\requirements.php on line 31
```

However it's already enable in php.ini file

extension=intl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [intl PHP extension is not working for xampp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480678/intl-php-extension-is-not-working-for-xampp-server), also [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

Comment: The is already icu.dll files in the bin.

Comment: Did you update the php.ini for Apache or CLI? They are often different. And did you restart Apache after that update?

Comment: Furthermore make sure that your globally accessible `php` executable is actually the one that you're configuring, `php --ini` should show you which ini file belongs to it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my php version was 7.3 and cake php was 4.0.1 so it was not compatible. Installing php 7.4 deemed solved.